# phonegap sqlitePlugin query "SELECT * FROM sms_list WHERE id=1" return error

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

i am using sqlitePlugin in my phonegap project and i have problem, i use this query  to get sms list

```
'SELECT * FROM sms_list WHERE category_id=' + id
```

but i got this error

```
"Error processing SQL: Error: a statement with no error handler failed: no such table: sms_list"
```

but the "sms_list" exist in fact.

I receive data when i am using this query 'SELECT * FROM sms_list".

I tried to execute 'SELECT * FROM sms_list WHERE category_id=1' in "sqliteman" and  it's working there.

Comment: maybe exists ... but not in the database that you are using ...

Comment: Did you open the correct database?

Comment: i use the correct database

Comment: how do you prove that the database table exists?

Comment: If your error is saying `no such table: sms_list`, then your table does not exist in the current instance. You may have created the table elsewhere, but it's not accessible here.

Comment: i am using prepopulated database, i just open it with "sqliteman"

Comment: yes? and why i receive data when i am using this query 'SELECT * FROM sms_list" ?

Comment: check this http://hansjar.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-easily-add-prepopulated-sqlite.html http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/7/27/Guest-Blog-Post-Shipping-a-populated-SQLite-DB-with-PhoneGap

Comment: yes i used the same java code, but i used this plugin https://github.com/millerjames01/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, problem was the [SqlitePlugin](https://github.com/millerjames01/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) what i used, i solve problem by using this [sqlitePlugin](https://github.com/RikshaDriver/Cordova-PrePopulated-SQLitePlugin).
 Thanks for the links [Aravin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541473/aravin) in which I found a link to my desired content.

Answer (score -1):

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM sms_list WHERE category_id=' + id,[], function(tx,rs){}, function() { 
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sms_list (name : type)');
});
```

if the table really does not exist, it gets created with this code.

Comment: table exist, i am using prepopulated database

Comment: Debug it. Check whether the Database is opened or not. may be thats the issue.